# Netflix zuul - игнорирование этапа проверки сертификата при редиректе к сервису, защищённому https

Tags: https, spring-boot

Есть spring boot сервис, запросы к этому сервису проксируются с помощью gateway-сервиса zuul (далее просто zuul). В случае, если сервис работает с обычным http-протоколом, всё работает как надо, никаких проблем нет.

Проблемы появляются, когда пытаешься заставить всё это работать через https. Я активировал https на сервисе, добавил self-signed сертификат, который сгенерировал с помощью keytool, и сервис стал доступен по https-протоколу. Однако zuul не может с ним работать, у него вылетает исключение:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Очевидно, это проблема возникла из-за того, что клиент, который используется в zuul, не может проверить мой сертификат

Я хочу сконфигурировать zuul таким образом, чтобы он игнорировал этап проверки сертификата, однако не понимаю как это сделать. Может кто с этим сталкивался и знает что делать?

P.S.: на zuul я явно настроил использования ribbon в качестве лоадбалансера:

```
ribbon.IsSecure=true
ribbon.restclient.enabled=true
```